# I'm trying hide div 1 when hovering it, then show div 2 when div 1 is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm in need of hiding a div on mouse hover and then show another div instead, I'm trying to achieve this by using css but when I test the code, both divs are hidden. Maybe this can only be achieved using jQuery?

I wrote down this code in pure CSS/HTML:

```css
.responsive-banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 154px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.responsive-banner a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner-description {
  /*width:70%;
      height:127px; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.banner-description-2 {
  padding: 7px;
  max-height: 127px;
  overflow: hidde
}

.banner-title {
  font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 1px;
  color: #000;
}

.banner-txt {
  font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.11rem;
  color: #000;
}

.banner-btn {
  background: #279fba;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 4px
}

a.banner-btn {
  color: #FF0000;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

a.banner-btn:hover {
  color: #5ca5ff;
}

#banneryoutube1 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  background-image: url(/image1.webp);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 246px;
  height: 138px;
  background-size: 246px 138px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#banneryoutube12 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  background-image: url(/image2.webp);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 246px;
  height: 138px;
  background-size: 246px 138px;
  background-color: transparent;
  /* animation: wahooMario 0.12s linear 1;*/
}

#showbannerinarticle1 {
  display: block
}

#showbannerinarticle2 {
  display: none
}

#showbannerinarticle1:hover {
  display: none
}

#showbannerinarticle2:hover {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div id="showbannerinarticle1" class="responsive-banner">
  <a href="/index.html" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
    <div id="banneryoutube1" /></div>
<div class="banner-description">
  <div class="banner-description-2">
    <div class="banner-title">
      1</div>
    <div class="banner-txt">LOREM IPSUM
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div id="showbannerinarticle2" class="responsive-banner">
  <a href="/index2.html" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
    <div id="banneryoutube12" /></div>
<div class="banner-description">
  <div class="banner-description-2">
    <div class="banner-title">
      1</div>
    <div class="banner-txt">LOREM IPSUM
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

How can I proceed with this?
Basically when I'm creating is an animated banner.

Comment: you have self-closing tags on your `div`-elements like `<div id="banneryoutube1" /></div>`

Answer (score 3):

The issue may be that CSS cannot consider something to be *hovered* unless it is visible, and so it gets confused.

I would wrap both in another div and target the CSS to the wrapper, like this:

```css
.wrapper:hover .hide-me {
  display: none;
}
.show-me {
    display:none;
}
.wrapper:hover .show-me {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hide-me">Content 1</div>
  <div class="show-me">Content 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement it, but everything got messed up so far. Do you have a working fiddle?

Comment: Content 2 should be initially hidden.

Comment: If you only want to use css, try positioning the second article as position absolute and then on hover change the z-index.  Not sure if that will work but it might.  Far easer to use JS

Comment: Here's what I did:

.responsivebannerwrapper:hover #responsivebannerhideme1 { display: none; }
.responsivebannerwrapper:hover #responsivebannershowme1 { display: block;}
.responsivebannerwrapper #responsivebannershowme1 { display: none; }

Comment: Now I'm wondering: is there any way to preload the images? Because the hidden ones will only load on mouse hover, that causes a delay to show the image.

Comment: I have fixed the code to make content 2 be initially hidden.

Comment: You could add separate img-blocks that are hidden by other means than `display:none`, to preload the images. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59739883/1678383

Comment: @user832 did my post answer your original question? If so, please mark it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Heres some workign example you can play with using jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".div1").hover(function(){
   $(".div2").show();
     $(".div1").hide();

});

  $(".div2").hover(function(){
   $(".div1").show();
     $(".div2").hide();

});
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;}

.div2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  display:none;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="div1">
<h1>This is my div 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="div2">
<h1>div 2 is now showing</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
document.getElementById('firstDivId').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('secondDivId').style.display = "block";
// Switch these around when doing the opposite
```

Comment: I'll only use javascript if I can't find a way through css.